# custom operator for priority queue in cpp

Tags: c++, priority-queue

Getting error while declaring priority queue like this with a custom operator

```
struct compare1{
         bool operator()(Interval &s1,Interval &s2){
             if(s1.start!=s2.start)return s1.start<s2.start;
             return s1.end<s2.end;
         }
     };
priority_queue(Interval,vector<Interval>,compare1)p;
```

Error->/code/Solution.cpp: In member function 'int Solution::minMeetingRooms(std::vector&)':
/code/Solution.cpp:33:23: error: missing template arguments before '(' token
priority_queue(Interval,vector,compare1)p;

^
/code/Solution.cpp:33:32: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
priority_queue(Interval,vector,compare1)p;

^
/code/Solution.cpp:33:49: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
priority_queue(Interval,vector,compare1)p;
^

/code/Solution.cpp:33:58: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
priority_queue(Interval,vector,compare1)p;

My whole code

```
class Solution {
public:
    /**
     * @param intervals: an array of meeting time intervals
     * @return: the minimum number of conference rooms required
     * 
     */
     static bool compare(Interval s1 ,Interval s2){
         if(s1.start!=s2.start)return s1.start<s2.start;
         return s1.end<s2.end;
     }

     struct compare1{
         bool operator()(Interval &s1,Interval &s2){
             if(s1.start!=s2.start)return s1.start<s2.start;
             return s1.end<s2.end;
         }
     };
    int minMeetingRooms(vector<Interval> &intervals) {

        sort(intervals.begin(),intervals.end(),compare);
        priority_queue(Interval,vector<Interval>,compare1)p;
        p.push(intervals[0]);
        int ans = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<intervals.size();i++){
            Interval curr = interevals[i];
            Interval earliest = p.top();
            p.pop();


            if(earliest.end<curr.start){
                earliest.start = min(earliest.start,interevals[i].start);
                earliest.end = max(earliest.end,intervals[i].end);
                pq.push(earliest);
                ans++;
            }
            else{
                p.push(interevals[i]);
            }

        }
        return ans;


    }
};
```

Comment: priority_queue is a template, check the syntax of template specialization.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

Answer (score 2):

Use this,

```
priority_queue<Interval,vector<Interval>,compare1> p;
```